# adding function to loops through

Tags: windows, sockets

I need to search in a big json nested collection which have unique IDs recursively. The collection contains key values or nested arrays which contains keys. Keys can be anywhere in the object. Keys can be number or string.

Please note: Key values are unique if they are not in array. If they are in array, the key duplicates per items in array. For example,

```
"WebData": {
      WA1: 3, //not in array so unique
      WA3: 2, so unique
      WA3: "NEO",
      WebGroup : [
    { Web1: 1, //duplicate Web1
              Web2: 2
            },
            { Web1: 2, //duplicate Web2
              Web2: 2
            }]
     }
```

What I want:
I will pass an array of keys in different variations for example

> 1. Not in Arrays: I will pass key return either their values or sum for example:

```
function(["WA1",""WA3", "RAE1"],"notsum")
```

If I pass (not sum)

```
["WA1",""WA3", "RAE1"]
```

and the operation is not "sum", it should return an array of their values from the collection

```
[3,2,1]
```

If I pass the same but operation is sum)

```
function(["WA1",""WA3", "RAE1"],"sum")

["WA1",""WA3", "RAE1"]
```

it should return sum from the collection

```
return 6
```

> 2. If in Array: If the value to search are in the array means they duplicate, then it should return me sum or their individual values again For example

```
["WEB1","Web2"]
```

. It could either return me,

```
[7,1]  //Again total of 3+4, 0+1 //see in example
```

or

```
[[3,4],[0,1]]  //Because values are duplicate and in array, just collect them
```

I need to do in an elegant way:

Full example of JSON:

```
{
  version: "1.0"
  submission : "editing"
  "WebData": {
          WA1: 3,
          WA3: 2,  
          WA3: "NEO",
          WebGroup : [
        { Web1: 3,
                  Web2: 0
                },
                { Web1: 4,
                  Web2: 1
                }]
  },
  "NonWebData": {
          NWA1: 3,
          NWA2: "INP",
          NWA3: 2,  
  },
  "FormInputs": {
          FM11: 3,
          FM12: 1,
          FM13: 2,

  "RawData" : {
     "RawOverview": {
            "RAE1" : 1,
            "RAE2" : 1,
     },
     "RawGroups":[
                 {
                 "name": "A1",
                 "id":   "1",
                 "data":{
                         "AD1": 'period',
                         "AD2": 2,
                         "AD3": 2,                        
                         "transfers": [
                                       {
                                            "type": "in",
                                            "TT1": 1,
                                            "TT2": 2,
                                       },
                                       {
                                            "type": "out",
                                            "TT1": 1,
                                            "TT2": 2,
                                       }
                ]
                           }
                  },
                 {
                 "name": "A2",
                 "id":   "2",
                 "data":{
                         "AD1": 'period',
                         "AD2": 2,
                         "AD3": 2,                        
                         "transfers": [
                                       {
                                            "type": "in",
                                            "TT1": 1,
                                            "TT2": 2,
                                       },
                                       {
                                            "type": "out",
                                            "TT1": 1,
                                            "TT2": 2,
                                       }
                ]
                           }
                  }
               ]
             },
            "Other":
               { O1: 1,
                 O2: 2,
                 O3: "hello"
               },
            "AddedBy": "name"
            "AddedDate": "11/02/2019"
         }
```

I am not able to write a function here, which can do this for me, my code is simply searching in this array, and I loop through to find it, which is I am sure not the correct way.

My code is not elegant, and I am using somehow repetitive functions. This is just one snippet, to find out the keys in one level. I want only 1 or 2 functions to do all this

```
function Search(paramKey, formDataArray) {
    var varParams = [];
    for (var key in formDataArray) {
        if (formDataArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = formDataArray[key];
            for (var ikey in val) {
                if (val.hasOwnProperty(ikey)) {
                    if (ikey == paramKey)
                        varParams.push(val[ikey]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return varParams;
}
```

> 3. One more test case if in Array: to Return only single array of values, without adding. (Update - I achieved this through editing the code following part)

```
 notsumsingle: function (target, key, value) {
                if (target[key] === undefined) {
                    target[key] = value;
                    return;
                }
                target.push(value);
            },

"groupData": [
            {
                "A1G1": 1,
                "A1G2": 22,
                "AIG3": 4,
                "AIG4": "Rob"
            },
            {
                "A1G1": 1,
                "A1G2": 41,
                "AIG3": 3,
                "AIG4": "John"
            },
            {
                "A1G1": 1,
                "A1G2": 3,
                "AIG3": 1,
                "AIG4": "Andy"
              }
        ],
```

perform(["AIG2",""AIG4"], "notsum")

It is returning me

```
[
    [
        22,
        41,
        3
    ]
],
[
    [
        "",
        "Ron",
        "Andy"
    ]
]
```

Instead, can I add one more variation "SingleArray" like "sum" and "notsum" and get the result as single Array.

```
    [
        22,
        41,
        3
    ]

    [
        "",
        "Ron",
        "Andy"
    ]
```

> 4th one, I asked, is it possible the function intelligent enough to pick up the sum of arrays or sum of individual fields automatically. for example, in your example,  you have used "sum" and "total" to identify that.

```
console.log(perform(["WA1", "WA3", "RAE1"], "total"));  // 6
console.log(perform(["Web1", "Web2"], "sum"));          // [7, 1]
```

Can the function, just use "sum" and returns single or array based on if it finds array, return [7,1] if not return 6

> 5th : I found an issue in the code, if the json collection is added this way

```
perform(["RAE1"], "notsum") //[[1,1]]
perform(["RAE1"], "sum")  //2
```

It returns [1, 1], or 2 although there is only one RAE1 defined and please note it is not an array []  so it should not be encoded into [[]] array,  just the object key

```
 "RawData" : {
 "RawOverview": {
        "RAE1" : 1,
        "RAE2" : 1,
 }
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Comment: I am not able to write a correct function here, my code is simply searching not recursively, and I loop through to find it, which is I am sure not the correct way

Comment: why not add your code?

Comment: edited/ added my code

Answer (score 0):

For making it easier, and to take the same interface for getting sums or not sums and a total, without any array, you could introduce another operation string `total` for getting the sum of all keys.

This approach takes an object for getting a function which either add an value to an array at the same index or stores the value at an specified index, which match the given keys array of the function.

For iterating the object, you could take the key/value pairs and iterate until no more object is found.

As result, you get an array, or the total sum of all items.

BTW, the keys of an object are case sensitive, for example `'WEB1'` does not match `'Web1'`.

```js
function perform(keys, operation) {
    function visit(object) {
        Object
            .entries(object)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => {
                if (k in indices) return fn(result, indices[k], v);
                if (v && typeof v === 'object') visit(v);
            });
    }

    var result = [],
        indices = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: i }))),
        fn = {
            notsum: function (target, key, value) {
                if (target[key] === undefined) {
                    target[key] = value;
                    return;
                }
                if (!Array.isArray(target[key])) {
                    target[key] = [target[key]];
                }
                target[key].push(value);
            },
            sum: function (target, key, value) {
                target[key] = (target[key] || 0) + value;
            }
        }[operation === 'total' ? 'sum' : operation];

    visit(data);
    return operation === 'total'
        ? result.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
        : result;
}

var data = { version: "1.0", submission: "editing", WebData: { WA1: 3, WA3: 2, WAX: "NEO", WebGroup: [{ Web1: 3, Web2: 0 }, { Web1: 4, Web2: 1 }] }, NonWebData: { NWA1: 3, NWA2: "INP", NWA3: 2 }, FormInputs: { FM11: 3, FM12: 1, FM13: 2 }, RawData: { RawOverview: { RAE1: 1, RAE2: 1 }, RawGroups: [{ name: "A1", id: "1", data: { AD1: 'period', AD2: 2, AD3: 2, transfers: [{ type: "in", TT1: 1, TT2: 2 }, { type: "out", TT1: 1, TT2: 2 }] } }, { name: "A2", id: "2", data: { AD1: 'period', AD2: 2, AD3: 2, transfers: [{ type: "in", TT1: 1, TT2: 2 }, { type: "out", TT1: 1, TT2: 2 }] } }] }, Other: { O1: 1, O2: 2, O3: "hello" }, AddedBy: "name", AddedDate: "11/02/2019" };

console.log(perform(["WA1", "WA3", "RAE1"], "notsum")); // [3, 2, 1]
console.log(perform(["WA1", "WA3", "RAE1"], "total"));  // 6
console.log(perform(["Web1", "Web2"], "sum"));          // [7, 1]
console.log(perform(["Web1", "Web2"], "notsum"));       // [[3, 4], [0, 1]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, sorry for delay, some travelling. thanks, I am going to test it. Question. I also have strings in the json collection, in that case, I just need them to return string values. Will it do it within certain scenario?

Comment: if you do not sum them ... what should happen then?

Comment: I thought so, after posting this. Just checking it, thanks.

Comment: One more question, sorry: If I just pass "sum", can the function be made intelligent enough to avoid 'sum' and 'total' to be passed separately, it will return if it is an array a collection of sum results?

Comment: actually no. it would be easier, if you add some more use cases to the question.

Comment: No problem, I am testing it with test cases, and I will add them up here all in one go, many thanks

Comment: Hi again, I have added one more test case [edited above] to return a single array, point number 3, can you please check? many thanks

Comment: Thanks, also added point number 4, what I meant to say, when I just say "sum" and return arrays or single value based on what it finds in collection for the keys